# Enumeration attribute not recognized

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, replit

This is the code I am running:

```
import Qubit
from Z import Z

q = Qubit(Z.V)
```

Qubit code looks like this:

```
from Z import Z

class Qubit:
  def __init__(self, spin):
    if isinstance(spin, Z):
      print ('success')
```

Z code looks like this:

```
from enum import Enum

class Z(Enum):
  H = 0
  V = 1
```

When I run the code, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    q = Qubit(Z.V)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Try `Z().V` and see what you get.

Comment: `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the enum `Z` is a member of the module `Z`, which means you need to refer to it as `Z.Z`, both in `main.py` and `Qubit`. Alternatively, you can replace `import Z` with `from Z import Z` in both files.

Comment: It still gives an error of:
`TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

Comment: I don't understand what is the error, please update your question with the new code and the traceback.

Comment: This is the exact same problem, `Qubit.Qubit`